# How to get array of array from parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have stored a array of array in parse in a column named **"Polygon"** like this:
    [[13.74653990489156,100.4923625509455],[13.74652348443379,100.4925687879127],[13.74636831105128,100.4925992163138],[13.74660230262049,100.4924453837896]]

But I am unable to access those data =rom parse.

I have tried this method:

```
 private func gettingPolygonsFromParse() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "AttractionPolygon")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (polygonsArray, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {                
            for polygon in polygonsArray as! [PFObject] {
               // I am unable to get polygon value from here. 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear if `Polygon` column belongs to `AttractionPolygon` class.

If yes, try this:

```
for polygon in polygonsArray as! [PFObject] {
    if let array1 = polygon["Polygon"] as? [[Double]] {
        for item in array1 {
            print(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey . Worked for me! :)